# Reproducir audio al cargar la pagina web

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Estoy realizando una página de un juego de preguntas, así que al cargar la página estoy poniendo que reproduzca un `audio` de intro, pero sale `error`, solo funciona si doy <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>, que sería traer todo del servidor, de lo contrario sale el error siguiente:

```
partida.php:172 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed  
because the user didn't interact with the document first.
```

He buscado sobre ese error y menciona sobre las nuevas políticas de los navegadores, pero ¿hay una forma de resolver este problema?

El código que tengo en mi pagina web es el siguiente:

```
<audio id="intro" src="../audio/intro.mp3"></audio>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        accionPlay();
    }
    function accionPlay(){  
        document.getElementById('intro').play();    
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Es simple si lo único que deseas es que el audio se reproduzca al inicio de la carga de la página.

Debes usar el atributo `autoplay` de la etiqueta `<audio>`, y el audio se reproducirá al inicio de la carga.

```
<audio id="intro" src="../audio/intro.mp3" autoplay></audio>
```

Ejemplo:

```html
<p>El audio se reproducirá al inicio de la carga de la página</p>

<audio controls="" autoplay>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Tu navegador no soporta el elemento "audio".
</audio>
```

[Aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp) puedes obtener más referencia sobre la etiqueta

Comment: Funciona en la primera carga de la pagina, después ya no reproduce el audio refrescando la pagina, al menos que de CTRL + F5. reproduce el audio.

Comment: Te bota el mismo error?

Comment: No sale error, y me percate que si termina la reproducción y espero un promedio de unos 40 segundos y refresca la página reproduce el audio. Es extraño. Aprecio tu apoyo por que ya no sale el error.

Comment: Quizás se deba al peso del audio, ¿cuanto pesa el archivo?

Comment: pesa 475kb duración 30s, debe ser eso gracias por tu respuesta.